# Flexbox child element expands the parent when it didn't reach the edge of the parent

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm making a chat bubble with flexbox, and there're three child elements in the container (`avatar`, `content`, `meta`).

---

## what I expected.

The `avatar`, `content` elements share the same row, and the `meta` element owns a row.

[image]

The container should fits the content.

[image]

---

## what actually happened.

The container expands based on the width of the text of the `meta` element even if the text hasn't reached the edge of the container.

[image]

---

## demo

Here's the code. Is it possible to **prevent** the container expands when the 
text of the `meta` element hasn't reached the edge of the container? *(without adding any wrappers or changing the `flex-direction`)*

```css
.chat {
  display       : flex;
  flex-wrap     : wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  width         : max-content;
  background    : black;
}

.chat .avatar {
  width     : 32px;
  height    : 32px;
  background: blue;
}

.chat .content {
  height    : 32px;
  background: yellow;
}

.chat .meta {
  width     : 100%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="chat">
  <div class="avatar"></div>
  <div class="content">
    This is a chat.
  </div>
  <div class="meta">
    10:31 AM
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of assigning a `width` to flexbox elements, use [`flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) or [`flex-basis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis).

```css
.chat {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: max-content;
  background: black;
}

.chat .avatar {
  flex: 0 0 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background: blue;
}

.chat .content {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  height: 32px;
  background: yellow;
}

.chat .meta {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="chat">
  <div class="avatar"></div>
  <div class="content">
    This is a chat.
  </div>
  <div class="meta">
    10:31 AM
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This expands the yellow content, but I want the container to shrink.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the yellow content to fill the space, just add `flex-grow: 1;` to it. You can avoid the container expansion by adding `display: inline-flex;` to it.

```css
.chat {
  display       : inline-flex;
  flex-wrap     : wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  width         : max-content;
  background    : black;
}

.chat .avatar {
  width     : 32px;
  height    : 32px;
  background: blue;
}

.chat .content {
  height    : 32px;
  background: yellow;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.chat .meta {
  width     : 100%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="chat">
  <div class="avatar"></div>
  <div class="content">
    This is a chat.
  </div>
  <div class="meta">
    10:31 AM
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved easily with display : grid

I am not sure if you want the black background to show. But it can be changed with a single line change (commented in the snippet)

```css
.chat {
  display       : inline-grid;
  background    : black;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
}

.chat .avatar {
  width     : 32px;
  height    : 32px;
  background: blue;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.chat .content {
  height    : 32px;
  background: yellow;
  grid-row: 1;
  justify-self: start; /* comment this line to make it expand */
}

.chat .meta {
  width     : 100%;
  background: red;
  grid-column: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="chat">
  <div class="avatar"></div>
  <div class="content">
    This is a chat.
  </div>
  <div class="meta">
    10:31 AM
  </div>
</div>
<div class="chat">
  <div class="avatar"></div>
  <div class="content">
    This is a chat.
  </div>
  <div class="meta">
    10:31 AM 10:31 AM 10:31 AM
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "flexbox" clearly appears in both the title and the tags for OP's question.

Comment: @Blazemonger and it is clearly very difficult to achieve in flexbox, but easy to achieve in grid, so it could be an XY problem.